# submeter variavel php e formulario com unico submit

Tags: php, jquery, formulário, input, get

boa noite pessoal,

Estou realizando um trabalho da minha faculdade e estou com dificuldade em um parte. Já pesquisei e tentei varias formas, como estou iniciando talvez tenha outro meio que desconheço.

Eu tenho duas paginas index.php e localizar.php, preciso enviar a variável id_pet para a pagina localizar, isso eu fiz usando get pela URL do link ate aqui consegui fazer tranquilo ta funcionando. Mas também preciso enviar a data inicial e final que esta num formulário. Queria fazer isso usando o mesmo botão que uso para enviar o id_pet.
Como meu botão de envio esta fora do formulário usei o Jquery pra submeter o formulário e funcionou usando esse código desde que o input do tipo submit esteja fora da tag "a" dai ele submete o formulário. Abaixo tem o código jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".btnLocalizar").click(function(){
    $("#formData").submit();
           });
       });
```

mas como quero enviar tudo com um botão tentei fazer o seguinte:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>" . $row["id_pet"]."</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row["nome_pet"]."</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row["nome_tutor"]."</td>";
     echo "<td>" . "<a href='localizar.php?id_pet=$row[id_pet]'>";
     echo "<input class='btn btn-primary btnLocalizar' type='submit' value='Localizar'>";
     echo "</a>";
     echo "</td>";
            }
```

Esse código php gera a minha tabela com o resultado do meu banco de teste mysql e ja inclui na tabela o link/submit que envia a variável id_pet para a pagina que preciso. Mas quando esta desta forma eu clico no botão e ele envia somente a variável do php e não submete o formulário da minha pagina usando o código javascript ali de cima.

Só que fiquei sem entender, se eu crio um input do tipo submit fora da tag "a" o código Jquery funciona normal e submete o formulário, mas ai fico sem ter como enviar a variável do php.

espero que tenha ficado claro a minha duvida, preciso enviar os dados do formulário e a variável php usando um único submit ou link se e que da de fazer isso.

desde ja obrigado

Comment: Onde fica o input fora do formulário

Comment: Porque se fica dentro de um form voce adicionar a variavel num  input hidden: ex: `<input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $id_pet ?>' name='id_ped'>`

Comment: Ou voce quer enviar todos os dados da tabela?

Comment: quando você mantem o input dentro da tag "a" e tenta dar um submit, aparece algum erro no console?

Comment: essa aqui e a linha do input: `echo "<input class='btn btn-primary btnLocalizar' type='submit' value='Localizar'>";`   eu preciso enviar da minha tabela mysql somente o id_Pet, mas queria enviar junto o conteúdo do meu formulário que fica antes dessa linha do submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes da resposta em si, gostaria de fazer umas observações:

- Se o botão está fora do formulário, não tem sentido ele ser do tipo `submit`. Altere o tipo para `button`, por que ele é apenas o gatilho para submeter o formulário de forma manual.
- Não coloque um botão dentro de uma tag `<a></a>`. Botão é uma coisa, link é outra. Cada qual possui uma função diferente.

Vamos a solução:

Certifique-se de que o `form` possui o `method="post"`, pois você irá receber no PHP os dados do formulário via `$_POST`. Apenas o `id_pet` será via `$_GET`.

Inclua no botão um atributo `data-id` com o id em questão:

```
echo "<input data-id='". $row["id_pet"] ."' class='btn btn-primary btnLocalizar' type='button' value='Localizar'>";
                ↑
```

E no jQuery você irá alterar o `action` do `form` com o valor desse `data-id` do botão clicado antes de submeter o formulário:

```
$(".btnLocalizar").click(function(){
   $("#formData")
   .attr("action", "localizar.php?id_pet="+$(this).data("id"))
   .submit();
});
```

> Não esqueça de retirar do código o `<a href='localizar.php?id_pet=$row[id_pet]'>` e o fechamento `</a>`.

Comment: Obrigado resolveu o problema, funcionou perfeitamente. Se puder só me explica melhor esse trecho de codigo, acho que entendi ele parcialmente, mas queria ter certeza se entendi certo o que ele faz.  `"$(this).data("id"))`

Comment: Legal q resolveu. O código eh o seguinte: o $(this) é o botao clicado, o data("id") pega o valor do atributo data-id... Se fosse data-qualquercoisa, seria $(this).data("qualquercoisa")

Comment: obrigado pela explicação, ajudou demais.